# ¿Alguien sabe como exportar mi local host de Xampp a internet?

Tags: laravel, xampp, dns

Estoy tratando de correr una aplicación en **laravel** y ya la levanto de manera local y con un *vhost*.

Mi problema es que **no se como crear un tunel** entre `xampp` y un `dominio real` para que cualquiera vea la información. La coneccion a **DB** es en **SQL** por eso no lo puedo subir a cpanel directamente.

¿Alguien sabe como crear este tunel entre la dirección ip y el puerto en donde corro laravel para vincularlo hacia un dominio real?

Comment: Creo que estás enfocando mal el asunto, lo que deberías hacer aquí es llevar todo al servidor remoto: base de datos, aplicación de Laravel, etc. Considera que el sitio será accedido al mismo tiempo quizá por miles o millones de personas y no creo que tu servidor local tenga capacidad para gestionar todo eso, a no ser que vivas en la NASA.

Comment: Tienes que contratar un hosting web, por ejemplo yo he usado godaddy ahi te permite importar tu propio proyecto, y crear la base de datos asignado a un dominio y puedes tener tu app online

Comment: Puedes utilizar Ngrok nos permite exponer a internet nuestro proyecto crea una URL generada dinámicamente, la cual apunta a un servicio web que se está ejecutando en nuestra maquina local.

Lo mejor en mi opinión es subir todo un VPS realizar pruebas y ver rendimiento de funcionamiento de la app, puedes hacer un Deploy en menos de 20 minutos, sin utilizar Cpanel o filezilla y actualizar todo desde un archivo envoy.blade.php